# How do you check the presence of an attribute with Selenium and get its value if it is here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I iterate on [a google form survey](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe-ebOztdB6T4ZgtsOYuvbUR5qwSTfI5CnJB1mNLeNflCVX8Q/viewform) and try to put some content (which I try to make look like a quote just in case). However some fields are ages and do not allow to be more than 99 years old like this:

```
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-label="Age" aria-describedby="i.desc.504994172 i.err.504994172" name="entry.128750970" value="" min="18" max="99" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="10102015" badinput="false" aria-invalid="true">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

So I added a condition in my code to try to see if there is a 'max' attribute on the elements I have to write on:

```
        content_areas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
            "quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
        )
        for content_area in content_areas:
            if content_area.get_attribute("max") exists:
                max = content_area.get_attribute("max")
                content_area.send_keys(max)
            else:
                content_area.send_keys("10102015")
```

But it doesn't work:

```
max:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "questions_scraper_michael.py", line 151, in <module>
    result = extract(driver, df, column)
  File "questions_scraper_michael.py", line 70, in extract
    "freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer"
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 580, in find_elements_
by_class_name
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements

    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_respo
nse
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: {Alert text :
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, your test involves:

- Check the presence of `max` attribute.
- If such elements are present, then retrieve the value of *max* attribute.

Ideally, the `max` attribute specifies the maximum value for an `<input>` element. So you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe-ebOztdB6T4ZgtsOYuvbUR5qwSTfI5CnJB1mNLeNflCVX8Q/viewform')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("max") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput.exportInput[max]")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe-ebOztdB6T4ZgtsOYuvbUR5qwSTfI5CnJB1mNLeNflCVX8Q/viewform')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("max") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput' and @max]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['99']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution should be like this

```
  content_areas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
            "quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
        )
        for content_area in content_areas:
            if content_area.get_attribute("max") and not content_area.get_attribute("max").isspace():
                max = content_area.get_attribute("max")
            else:
                content_area.send_keys("10102015")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess the double dot `content_area..` is a typo? Unfortunately even without that it doesn't allow me to get this attribute yet. I've provided a full link to the webpage I'm scraping from. It's a google form.

Answer (score 1):

Try below `css` selector to identify all `input` elements on that page and then iterate the loop.

```
driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe-ebOztdB6T4ZgtsOYuvbUR5qwSTfI5CnJB1mNLeNflCVX8Q/viewform')
content_areas=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input.exportInput")
for content_area in content_areas:
    if content_area.get_attribute("max"):
        max = content_area.get_attribute("max")
        content_area.send_keys(max)
    else:
        content_area.send_keys("10102015")
```

**Browser Snapshot.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no "exists" command in python.
You should remove it.

```
for content_area in content_areas:
    if content_area.get_attribute("max"):
        max = content_area.get_attribute("max")
    else:
        content_area.send_keys("10102015")
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I just wrote it to mention that it had to be accessible. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it with your help yet. I am going to provide the url to the webpage which is a google forms survey